# How to verify two elements have the same value in Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

I have an element1 with text and  I clicked on this element1 and it takes me to a different page and I click on another element2 and takes me back to element1. but element1 should have same text as element2 because it got updated when I clicked on element2. How would you Verify it in Appium?

I'm confused how to verify it if element2 is on different page

```
      String txt1=element1.getText("same");
      String txt2=element2.getText("same");

      if(txt1.equals(txt2))
      {
      System.out.println("Success");
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println("Failure");
      }
```

Comment: getText() doesn't take any argument.

Comment: getAttributes(). I'm confused how would you verify if two elements have the same value text if one is on different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check that by verifying Titles before fetching value of an element:

```
  //current first page
  String firstPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
  String txt1=element1.getText();
  element1.click();

  //current page Second
  String secondPageTitle = driver.getTitle();

  if(!secondPageTitle.equals(firstPageTitle )){
  String txt2=element2.getText();
  }
  //verify if element texts are equal
  if(txt1.equals(txt2))
  {
  System.out.println("Success");
  }
  else
  {
  System.out.println("Failure");
  }
```

Comment: It can give same result as we match text of them

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..It will compare your two expect value.

```
assertEquals(txt1,txt2,"txt1 And txt2 is not same");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example of Amazon website where pages are differnt but value of gettext is same

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String titleFirstPage=driver.getTitle();
WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-
logo']/a[1]/span[1]"));
String element1Text=element1.getText();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tile-top']/div[2]/a/span")).click();
String titleSecondPage=driver.getTitle();
WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-logo']/a[1]/span[1]"));
String element2Text=element2.getText();

if (!titleFirstPage.equals(titleSecondPage)) {
    System.out.println("Differnt page");
    if(element1Text.equals(element2Text))
    {
        System.out.println("Amazon title is same");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("not matched");
    }

}
else
{
    System.out.println("Smoething is not correct");
}
```

Comment: It's different elements but have to have same text on them.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the text of each element you want to compare with following syntax.

```
String text1=element1.getText();
```

Now you could use an if statement or assert if the 2 texts are equal.

Comment: that was very kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

To check if two elements or a string is been displayed on the intended element.

```
assert(firstText.contains(secondText));
```

This will return True if the case passes, and False if the case fails.